# Cannot commit main.storyboard and .xcuserdata file on svn?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have tried lots of ways to commit main.storyboard and .xcuserdata file on svn. But I got following error.

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: PUT request on '/Main.storyboard' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I can commit all the file except those two file.

I am using svnX 1.3.4 version
please help.

Comment: Are u sure these two files are tracked? if these two files even if u atleast once ever did untrack then its not allow to commit your changes.

Comment: @ShrikantKankatti so how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please just take update first before committing the files because sometimes SVN don't allow to commit if many files are in update OR just add both files to working copy first, if its not tracked and than try to commit.